# Create directory working using java console but not using Tomcat Web application in centos

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, centos

I want to make a new folder in Centos using my Java Spring Web application, but its not working. The code works perfectly in Windows and also made a similar console application and ran it on Centos directly via terminal, it worked too. But I am unable to create a new folder via my Java Spring web application on centos.
Here is my code which makes a new folder:

```
long lastPost= 4;
lastPost++;
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir").toString());
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + lastPost).mkdir();
```

Comment: Maybe a write permission which is not set, or a selinux property which is blocking (try after `setenforce permissive`).

Comment: How to grant tomcat users permission to create new folder in centOs